# Uncaught Error: MUI: withStyles is no longer exported from @mui/material/styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import { withStyles } from '@mui/material/styles'
```

I want to use `withStyles` from material-ui in react app. But the console says like this.

```
Uncaught Error: MUI: withStyles is no longer exported from @mui/material/styles.
```

Is that no longer available in MUI? So What's the alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you upgrading from material-ui v4 to v5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this same error when I was upgrading from material-ui v4 to v5. I had to install the @mui/styles package, among other things.

More detailed info can be found [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/).

Answer (score 0):

In v5, Material UI has introduced styled components which is the alternative of withStyles.

You can read the documentation here - [Styled components MUI](https://mui.com/system/styled/)